# Text consoles on Linux don't work, caused by nVidia driver

Tags: linux, console, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm using Kubuntu 9.04, a GeForce 9800M GS (laptop) video card with nVidia's drivers, version 180. If I press Ctrl-Alt-F1 (or F2-F6) I should go to a fullscreen text console (instead of the X server running on terminal 7). This works if I use the default drivers, but not if I use the nVidia ones. Instead, it goes to a fully black screen (backlight off), with sound no longer audible (songbird is so nice to actually pause the music)

(How) can I solve this? I need the nVidia drivers, or stuff will be slow and ugly.

Here is my xorg.conf. You should know that I've never touched it, it's all automatically managed:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier      "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "Default Screen"
    Monitor         "Configured Monitor"
    Device          "Configured Video Device"
    DefaultDepth    24
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load    "glx"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier      "Configured Video Device"
    Driver  "nvidia"
    Option  "NoLogo"        "True"
EndSection
```

Comment: could you post your `xorg.conf`? It could help in finding a solution.

Comment: Ok i've posted it. It's rather short though.

Comment: When you press Ctrl-Alt-Fn nothing happens?

Comment: Woops, forgot to explain that. Edited my question

Comment: Please post your Xorg.0.log

Comment: @fpmurphy: See my answer below, new drivers fixed this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to Kubuntu 9.10. It has new nVidia drivers (version 185 I think) which fixed this problem

Answer (score 0):

If that's your complete xorg.conf, it's highly incomplete.  It's missing descriptions of your mouse and keyboard, for two.  It also doesn't set a resolution anywhere, e.g.

```
Option:      "metamodes" "CRT: nvidia-auto-select +1280+0, DFP: nvidia-auto-select +0 +0"
```

You may want to regenerate xorg.conf, for instance by running "sudo nvidia-settings".

Comment: in jaunty (ubuntu 9.04) xorg.conf is extremely minimal; they're phasing it to a detect-everything mode.  this is why mouse & kbd are missing.  karmic (9.10) won't even install an xorg.conf, tho supposedly you can create your own if needed.